# AWS ECS: Traffic to container port being rejected

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS Fargate application behind an ALB. All resources created by Terraform. My container runs on port 3000. I'm seeing rejections of all traffic on the port between the subnets.

In an effort to debug, I've ensured no NACL rules, (allow *), and even made the security groups as open as possible.

```
ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```

Yet I see the following in the VPC flow logs:

`2 169684143165 <my-eni> 10.0.6.141 10.0.113.1 59086 3000 6 3 180 1677082247 1677082253 REJECT OK`

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I can share more code if needed.

EDIT: My main.tf is here: https://gist.github.com/allenfisher/850da48b009790a631459285e974f762

Comment: Run the command in your machine `telnet 10.0.113.1 3000`. If the connection is successful, it means that traffic is flowing correctly. If the connection fails, it means that there is an issue with the networking configuration.

Comment: That does fail... however I'm stumped as to what networking configuration I need to fix. It's literally a stock VPC with 2 public/2 private subnets, an IGW a NAT GW. The security groups are wide open right now. I've run the reachability analyzer for both ENIs and they can see each other just fine.

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL that's an internal IP address. That command would only work from another machine in the same VPC.

Comment: @AllenFisher please share your terraform code, including the task definition, ECS service, load balancer listener, and target group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `network_configuration` block for the service was incorrect... the security group for the service was not specified... there's a default VPC in the account and it was getting associated with that. Fix is change:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
  ...

  network_configuration {
    subnets = [
      aws_subnet.my_public_subnet1.id,
      aws_subnet.my_public_subnet2.id
    ]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
...
}
```

To

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
...

  network_configuration {
    subnets = [
      aws_subnet.my_public_subnet1.id,
      aws_subnet.my_public_subnet2.id
    ]
    assign_public_ip = true
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.service_security_group.id]
  }
...
}
```